# Replace entire numbers in str_replace

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, preg-match-all

I have a string that contains numbers and I need to colour code each number in the string.

My preg_match_all gives me an array containing the right numbers (5, 280, 51). I need to colour the first number as red, second as blue and third as black.

Currently, the third number (51) isn't colouring correctly. The 5 is being coloured as red and the 1 is then ignored. I need the whole number (51) to be coloured black.

I believe my code is matching the 5, then matching the 280, then it's matching the next 5 without taking into account the following 1. How could I go about resolving this?

```
$coloursArray = array('red', 'blue', 'black');
$string = "dbase 5% used - 280G free | audit 51% used";

preg_match_all('#\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?#', $string, $matches);
for ($k = 0; $k < count($matches[0]); $k++)
{
    $string = str_replace($matches[0][$k], '<strong><span style="color: '.$coloursArray[$k].';">' . $matches[0][$k] . '</span></strong>', $string);
}
```

Outputs:

```
dbase <strong><span style="color: red">5</span></strong>% used
- <strong><span style="color: blue">280</span></strong>G free
| audit <strong><span style="color: red">5</span></strong>1% used
```

Last line should be:

```
| audit <strong><span style="color: black">51</span></strong>% used
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call to `str_replace` is replacing both of the `5`s in the string. This means that the third call does nothing.

As your array `$matches` contains the digits that you want to replace, you can use `preg_replace` like this:

```
$coloursArray = array('red', 'blue', 'black');
$string = "dbase 5% used - 280G free | audit 51% used";

preg_match_all('#\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?#', $string, $matches);

for ($k = 0; $k < count($matches[0]); $k++)
{
    $string = preg_replace("/(\D){$matches[0][$k]}(\D)/", '$1<strong><span style="color: '.$coloursArray[$k].';">' . $matches[0][$k] . '</span></strong>$2', $string);
}

echo $string;
```

Here I've captured the non-digit characters before and after each number using `(\D)` and added them to the replacement string using `$1` and `$2`.

Output:

```
dbase <strong><span style="color: red;">5</span></strong>% used - <strong><span style="color: blue;">280</span></strong>G free | audit <strong><span style="color: black;">51</span></strong>% used
```

---

Alternatively, you can do the whole thing in one go, using `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$coloursArray = array('red', 'blue', 'black');
$string = "dbase 5% used - 280G free | audit 51% used";

$c = 0;
$string = preg_replace_callback('#\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?#', function($x) use (&$c, $coloursArray) { 
    return '<strong><span style="color: '.$coloursArray[$c++].';">' . $x . '</span></strong>'; 
}, $string);
```

Each match is passed to the callback function and the replacement is performed, using `$c++` to select a different index from the array each time.

Comment: @Nathan no problem, please see my update for a more concise way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Use this lookaround based regex to avoid matching unwanted text:

```
$coloursArray = array('red', 'blue', 'black');
$string = "dbase 5% used - 280G free | audit 51% used";

preg_match_all('#(?<!\d)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?(?!\d)#', $string, $matches);
for ($k = 0; $k < count($matches[0]); $k++) {
   $string = preg_replace('/(?<!\d)' . $matches[0][$k] . '(?!\d)/', 
        '<strong><span style="color: '.$coloursArray[$k].';">' . $matches[0][$k] . '</span></strong>', $string);
}
echo $string;
```

**Output:**

> `base <strong><span style="color: red;">5</span></strong>% used - <strong><span style="color: blue;">280</span></strong>G free | audit <strong><span style="color: black;">51</span></strong>% used`

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? That doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: The reason why OP code is not right is that the first match is `5`. So, all `5`s are replaced with `str_replace` in the first place, and your regex just does not match `51` later. Possible solutions are either to obtain all matches, sort them by length, and then use `str_replace`, or iterate through all matches and replace each just once right where the match was found.

Comment: ok check updated answer for full answer. This is producing correct output as desired by OP.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm marking Tom's answer as my accepted one as it does exactly what I needed. I really appreciate your time though, thank you very much :)

Comment: That regex won't match number at start/end for ex test that with input as `"5% used - 280G free | audit 51"`